# Ошибка access violation при добавление элементов CRecentFileList на Windows 8 и старше

Tags: c++, mfc

У меня возник такой неприятный момент в проекте с использованием MFC. Имеется класс, наследник от `CWinApp`. Имеется переопределенный метод `AddToRecentFileList` примерно такой:

```
MyClass::AddToRecentFileList(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
 ...
 if (m_pRecentFileList != NULL)
    m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName);
 ...
}
```

На Windows 7 все работает нормально, но на Windows 8 и старше на строчке `Add` падает с ошибкой "access violation". Сейчас скажите, что нужно писать что-то типо того:

```
MyClass::AddToRecentFileList(LPCTSTR lpszPathName)
{
 ...
 if (m_pRecentFileList != NULL)
    if(WINVER >= 0x0601)
        m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName, m_pszAppID);
    else
        m_pRecentFileList->Add(lpszPathName);
 ...
}
```

Пробовал, во-первых, параметр `m_pszAppID` пустой, а во-вторых `winver` не определяется. Может есть какая-то функция для Windows 8 и старше для добавления в список или есть какой-то другой способ.